# How can I install codecs on my Ubuntu iso?

Tags: iso, codecs, media

I would like to install codecs and all the restricted media jazz for all my non internet connected Ubuntu users who would like to upgrade. How can I best do this?

Comment: You can download all needed codecs and give them on the cd or you can customize Ubuntu CD with [UCK](http://lichota.net/~krzysiek/projects/ubuntu-livecd-customization/).

Answer (score 1):

### Ubuntu Customization Kit

#### Description:

> UCK is a tool that helps you customizing official Ubuntu Live CDs (including Kubuntu/Xubuntu and Edubuntu) to your needs. You can add any package to the live system like, for example, language packs, applications, etc.

#### Features:

> Create bootable LiveCD with predefined languages based upon an original Ubuntu/Kubuntu live CD using graphical wizard.
> Build live CD with special features using scripts. It is possible to customize the root filesystem (for example install/remove packages), ISO contents (add/remove docs, change names) and initrd (add modules to boot, change boot sequence).

#### Screenshots:

[image]

#### Download

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try AptOnCD, it's available in the Software Center.

[image: Install via the software center]

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu This may Help you.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.